# Keys on Google App Engine are ordered

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I'm creating a object with JDO and let the GAE set the Key for me.

```
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
```

As results of the `PersistenceManager.makePersistent(myObject)`, I have a key with a long value that seem to be ordered. I have alread looking for on GAE documentation, but I cannot find where that is explicity documented. Is this genereated key ordered by creation?

I know that is not incremental.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK keys are assigned in ranges. See `DatastoreService.allocateIDs()`.

As far as I have observed, each instance gets a range. So when entities are created IDs are icremental within a range, but they are not ordered as they come from different ranges.

I'm guessing: you are trying to find out which entities are new? Add a timestamp property then [check for updates via cursors](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Query_Cursors).

Comment: This is a sad news. I'm trying to create a index for o Entity Groups, and I would link to sort my entities with the time of creation. This means that I should add the timestamp column to my entities? There is no other way?

Comment: @Victor Distributed systems are hard, and monotonically increasing IDs are impractical in a distributed system. A timestamp is a better idea all around.

Comment: Set a timestamp. Indexing and querying on a single column is very fast.

Comment: I solve that problem using the string timestamp + user_id as key of my entity. So I can sort by time and have not collision problems! Sucess!!

Comment: You could also have user as parent entity and not have collisions